# Does the Node --inspect flag have any notable performance impact?

Tags: node.js

Not much to expand on beyond the title. I'm considering leaving the --inspect flag on my Node EC2 instances for debugging purposes at will, and I just want to check if there are any notable performance concerns (or security holes) from doing so.

Comment: Note that you may turn on the inspection endpoint on-the-fly by sending `SIGUSR1` signal to the running node process. That can be done with `kill` command => `kill -s USR1 <pid>` where <pid> is the process id

Comment: And if you are running your node process in docker you may use `docker kill` => `docker kill --signal=USR1 <container>` where <container> is the name or ID of the container

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Lets divide the question into two.

###### Does `--inspect` flag `without a debugger attached` have any notable performance impact?

- No

###### Does `--inspect` flag `with a debugger attached` have any notable performance impact?

- Yes

#### TLTR:

When you use `--inspect` flag, you tell your `nodejs` process to listen for a specific port (`9229` by default) and accept remote connections of a debugging client via `ws` protocol. Until you have a connection to this port, your `nodejs` performance stays the same as if you don't have this flag.

This was not always the case though. In 2019 this issue was raised https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/28741 stating that having `--inspect-brk` flag raises CPU usage to 100%.

This commit by Eugene Ostroukhov fixed the issue https://github.com/nodejs/node/commit/49144ab64d3c5810f70585c2ccb0c90539fec116 and affected this releases:
`v17.4.0  v17.3.1 v17.3.0 v17.2.0 v17.1.0 v17.0.1 v17.0.0 v16.13.2 v16.13.1 v16.13.0 v16.12.0 v16.11.1 v16.11.0 v16.10.0 v16.9.1 v16.9.0 v16.8.0 v16.7.0 v16.6.2 v16.6.1 v16.6.0 v16.5.0 v16.4.2 v16.4.1 v16.4.0 v16.3.0 v16.2.0 v16.1.0 v16.0.0 v15.14.0 v15.13.0 v15.12.0 v15.11.0 v15.10.0 v15.9.0 v15.8.0 v15.7.0 v15.6.0 v15.5.1 v15.5.0 v15.4.0 v15.3.0 v15.2.1 v15.2.0 v15.1.0 v15.0.1 v15.0.0 v14.19.0 v14.18.3 v14.18.2 v14.18.1 v14.18.0 v14.17.6 v14.17.5 v14.17.4 v14.17.3 v14.17.2 v14.17.1 v14.17.0 v14.16.1 v14.16.0 v14.15.5 v14.15.4 v14.15.3 v14.15.2 v14.15.1 v14.15.0 v14.14.0 v14.13.1 v14.13.0 v14.12.0 v14.11.0 v14.10.1 v14.10.0 v14.9.0 v14.8.0 v14.7.0 v14.6.0 v14.5.0 v14.4.0 v14.3.0 v14.2.0 v14.1.0 v14.0.0 v13.14.0 v13.13.0 v13.12.0 v13.11.0 v13.10.1 v13.10.0 v13.9.0 v13.8.0 v13.7.0 v13.6.0 v13.5.0 v13.4.0 v13.3.0 v13.2.0 v13.1.0 v13.0.1 v13.0.0`

Finally, it was fixed in `^v12.7.0` with this pull request: https://github.com/nodejs/node/pull/28817

##### Now, what if we have a debugger client connected?

If we have a connected debugger client you will experience huge performance impact, estimate CPU intensive code to be about 100-300 times slower. I/O related code is not impacted though.

##### `debugger` keyword.

This keyword is not related to `--inspect` flag directly. It works when you run your `node` process with `inspect` argument and opens debugging client in the `REPL`.
https://nodejs.org/api/debugger.html

###### WARNING

This keyword affects the performance even if you don't have any debugging session running e.g. you started your application normally with `node my-app.js`.

Answer (score 0):

I did not notice any performance difference while running the benchmarks for my app with `--inspect`.

It is what I expected considering "browser" JavaScript always have debugging features activated. If those features would slow down V8, they wouldn't be activated by default on Chrome.

I guess the only reason debugging is not always activated on Node is for security concerns. Check Rolf answer for more info about security.

Answer (score -2):

Performance: To let you know that having a "debugger" statement in your Node.js source code has a bad impact on performance. So I assume that running the node.js programme in debug-mode has the same bad performance impact. Read more at 
https://medium.com/the-node-js-collection/get-ready-a-new-v8-is-coming-node-js-performance-is-changing-46a63d6da4de

Secure: by default the node.js process can only be debugged from the same localhost and on a specific port 9229 so that is secure. If you use something like 'node --inspect-brk=myhost.example.com:9229 ./index.js' for remote debugging then the debugger is exposed to the outside world (if that port is opened in the [Linux] firewall and if the DNS name is public).